# The application crashes on startup

Tags: android, kotlin

The application crashes at startup. What is this error and how to fix it, I do not understand

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: ru.bruimafia.pixabaylite, PID: 11137
                 java.lang.Error: Can not init animatorClazz instance
                    at androidx.appcompat.app.r.t(SourceFile:109)
                    at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.c.onAnimationEnd(SourceFile:12)
                    at android.graphics.animation.RenderNodeAnimator.onFinished(RenderNodeAnimator.java:370)
                    at android.animation.RevealAnimator.onFinished(RevealAnimator.java:43)
                    at android.graphics.animation.RenderNodeAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

[image]

This is the class code MainActivity class. What's wrong here? The application starts and crashes with an error. Splashscreen has time to load. This is the class code MainActivity class. What's wrong here? The application starts and crashes with an error. Splashscreen has time to loadThis is the class code MainActivity class. What's wrong here? The application starts and crashes with an error. Splashscreen has time to load

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

    private var TAG = "ADS"

    private lateinit var consentInformation: ConsentInformation
    private var isMobileAdsInitializeCalled = AtomicBoolean(false)
    private lateinit var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
    private lateinit var bind: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var appUpdateManager: AppUpdateManager
    private var adapter: ImageAdapter = ImageAdapter()
    private lateinit var disposable: Disposable
    private lateinit var searchView: SearchView
    private lateinit var bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog
    //private var googleInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    private var yandexInterstitialAd: YandexInterstitialAd? = null
    private var bannerAd: YandexBannerAdView? = null
    private lateinit var bp: BillingProcessor

    private var order = "popular"
    private var query = ""
    private var page = 1

    private fun initializeMobileAdsSdk() {
        if (isMobileAdsInitializeCalled.get()) {
            return
        }
        isMobileAdsInitializeCalled.set(true)

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this)

        // TODO: Request an ad.
        // InterstitialAd.load(...)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bind = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(bind.toolbar)


        bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(bind.root.context, getString(R.string.billing_license_key), this)
        bp.initialize()

        if (bp.isPurchased(getString(R.string.billing_product_id)))
            SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion = true

        checkPermission()
        loadData(query, order, page)
        //initGoogleAdsInterstitial()
        initYandexAdsInterstitial()
        loadingYandexAdsBanner()
        checkUpdateAvailability()

        adapter.setReachEndListener(object : ImageAdapter.OnReachEndListener {
            override fun onLoad() {
                bind.progressBarHor.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                loadData(query, order, page)
            }
        })

        adapter.setSaveButtonListener(object : ImageAdapter.OnSaveButtonListener {
            override fun onSave(image: Image, position: Int) {
                showYandexAdsInterstitial()
                downloadFile(image.imageURL.replace("https://pixabay.com/get/", ""))
            }
        })

        adapter.setSearchTagListener(object : ImageAdapter.OnSearchTagListener {
            override fun onSearch(title: String) {
                searchView.setQuery(title, true)
                searchView.isIconified = false
                searchView.clearFocus()
                loadData(title, order, page)
            }
        })

        bind.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            page = 1
            loadData(query, order, page)
        }

        bind.fab.setOnClickListener { bind.recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(0) }

        bind.recycler.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                if (dy > 0)
                    bind.fab.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                else
                    bind.fab.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        })

        if (SharedPreferencesManager.isFirstLaunch)
            showAlertDialog()

    }

    // сервис в РФ заблокирован
    private fun showAlertDialog() {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, null)
        bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme)

        view.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btn_ok).setOnClickListener {
            SharedPreferencesManager.isFirstLaunch = false
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
        }

        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view)
        bottomSheetDialog.show()
    }

    // проверка разрешений
    private fun checkPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 0)
        }
    }

    // проверка обновлений
    private fun checkUpdateAvailability() {
        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
        val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
            ) {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                    this,
                    8
                )
            }
        }
    }

    // окно выставления оценки и отзыва
    private fun requestReview() {
        val reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
        val requestReviewFlow = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow()

        requestReviewFlow.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
            if (request.isSuccessful) {
                val reviewInfo = request.result
                val flow = reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
                flow.addOnCompleteListener {
//                    SharedPreferencesManager.isPlayRating = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // меню и строка поиска
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)

        menu?.findItem(R.id.action_buy)?.isVisible = !bp.isPurchased(getString(R.string.billing_product_id))

        val searchManager = getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        searchView = menu!!.findItem(R.id.action_search).actionView as SearchView
        searchView.maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE
        searchView.queryHint = getString(R.string.menu_search)
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(newText: String?): Boolean {
                query = newText ?: ""
                page = 1
                bind.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                loadData(query, order, page)
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                query = newText ?: ""
                page = 1
                bind.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                loadData(query, order, page)
                return false
            }
        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    // выбор пунктов меню
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.action_sort) {
            when (order) {
                "popular" -> {
                    order = "latest"
                    page = 1
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_popular)
                    showMessage(getString(R.string.sort_by_latest))
                }

                "latest" -> {
                    order = "popular"
                    page = 1
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_latest)
                    showMessage(getString(R.string.sort_by_popular))
                }
            }
            loadData(query, order, page)
        }

        if (item.itemId == R.id.action_buy) {
            bp.purchase(this, getString(R.string.billing_product_id))
        }

        if (item.itemId == R.id.action_about) {
            AboutDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, "AboutDialog")
        }

        return true
    }

    // загрузка данных
    private fun loadData(q: String, order: String, page: Int) {
        disposable = ApiClient.getClient("https://pixabay.com/api/")
            .create(ApiService::class.java)
            .getImages(q, order, page)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { imagesResponse ->
                    if (page <= 1)
                        showData(imagesResponse.images as MutableList<Image>)
                    else
                        showLoadedData(imagesResponse.images as MutableList<Image>)
                },
                { throwable -> showMessage(throwable.message) }
            )
    }

    // показ данных
    private fun showData(list: MutableList<Image>) {
        adapter.setList(list)
        bind.recycler.adapter = adapter
        page++
        bind.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        bind.swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
    }

    // показ подгруженных данных
    private fun showLoadedData(list: MutableList<Image>) {
        adapter.updateList(list)
        page++
        bind.progressBarHor.visibility = View.GONE
        requestReview()
    }

    // показ сообщения
    private fun showMessage(msg: String?) {
        Snackbar.make(bind.root, msg + "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    // скачивание файла
    private fun downloadFile(url: String) {
        showMessage(getString(R.string.download_started))
        startNotificationDownload()
        disposable = Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://pixabay.com/get/")
            .build()
            .create(ApiService::class.java)
            .downloadImage(url)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(
                {
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                            saveFileWithAPI29(it.body()!!, url)
                        else
                            saveFileBeforeAPI29(it.body()!!, url)
                        stopNotificationDownload()
                    }
                },
                { throwable -> showMessage(throwable.message) }
            )
    }

    // сохранение файла API>=29
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private fun saveFileWithAPI29(body: ResponseBody, name: String): Boolean {

        val fos: OutputStream
        val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(body.byteStream())

        try {
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "pixabaylite_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg")
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
                put(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "PixabayLite"
                )
            }

            val imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            fos = contentResolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri)!!)!!

            try {
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos)
                Objects.requireNonNull(fos)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e.toString())
            } finally {
                fos.close()
            }

            return true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.toString())
        }

        return false
    }

    // сохранение файла API<29
    private fun saveFileBeforeAPI29(body: ResponseBody, name: String): Boolean {
        try {
            val mediaStorageDir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "PixabayLite")
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs())
                    showMessage(getString(R.string.error_create_folder))
            }

            val file = File(mediaStorageDir, "pixabaylite_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg")
            body.byteStream().use { input ->
                file.outputStream().use { output -> input.copyTo(output) }
            }

            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(file.absolutePath), null, null)

            return true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.toString())
        }

        return false
    }

    /*
    // показ межстраничной Google рекламы в приложении
    private fun showGoogleAdsInterstitial() {
        if (googleInterstitialAd != null && !SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion)
            googleInterstitialAd?.show(this)
        else if (googleInterstitialAd == null && yandexInterstitialAd?.isLoaded == true && !SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion)
            yandexInterstitialAd?.show()
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Google & Yandex: the interstitial ad wasn't ready yet")
    }
    */

    // показ межстраничной Yandex рекламы в приложении
    private fun showYandexAdsInterstitial() {
        if (yandexInterstitialAd?.isLoaded == true && !SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion)
            yandexInterstitialAd?.show()
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: the interstitial ad wasn't ready yet")
    }

    /*
    // инициализация межстраничной Google рекламы в приложении
    private fun initGoogleAdsInterstitial() {
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

        InterstitialAd.load(
            this,
            getString(R.string.ads_google_interstitialAd_id),
            adRequest,
            object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Google (onAdFailedToLoad): " + adError.message)
                    googleInterstitialAd = null
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Google: onAdLoaded")
                    googleInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
                    googleInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Google: onAdDismissedFullScreenContent")
                            showMessage(getString(R.string.download_started))
                            googleInterstitialAd = null
                            initGoogleAdsInterstitial()
                        }

                        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Google: onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent")
                            googleInterstitialAd = null
                            initGoogleAdsInterstitial()
                            // если с google ошибка, то тогда показываем рекламу Яндекс
                            if (yandexInterstitialAd?.isLoaded == true)
                                yandexInterstitialAd?.show()
                        }

                        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Google: onAdShowedFullScreenContent")
                        }
                    }

                }
            })
    }
    */

    // инициализация межстраничной Яндекс рекламы в приложении
    private fun initYandexAdsInterstitial() {
        yandexInterstitialAd = YandexInterstitialAd(this)
        yandexInterstitialAd?.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ads_yandex_interstitialAd_unitId))
        yandexInterstitialAd?.loadAd(YandexAdRequest.Builder().build())
        yandexInterstitialAd?.setInterstitialAdEventListener(object : InterstitialAdEventListener {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: onAdLoaded")
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adRequestError: YandexAdRequestError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex (onAdFailedToLoad): " + adRequestError.description)
                yandexInterstitialAd = null
                initYandexAdsInterstitial()
            }

            override fun onImpression(impressionData: YandexImpressionData?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: onImpression")
            }

            override fun onAdShown() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: onAdShown")
            }

            override fun onAdDismissed() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: onAdDismissed")
                yandexInterstitialAd = null
                initYandexAdsInterstitial()
                showMessage(getString(R.string.download_started))
            }

            override fun onAdClicked() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: onAdClicked")
            }

            override fun onLeftApplication() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: onLeftApplication")
            }

            override fun onReturnedToApplication() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex: onReturnedToApplication")
            }

        })
    }

    // инициализация и отображение баннера Яндекс рекламы в приложении
    private fun loadingYandexAdsBanner() {
        bannerAd = bind.bannerAdView
        bannerAd!!.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ads_yandex_banner_id))
        bannerAd!!.setAdSize(AdSize.stickySize(this, Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels))

        val adRequest = YandexAdRequest.Builder().build()

        bannerAd!!.setBannerAdEventListener(object : YandexBannerAdEventListener {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex Banner: ")
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: YandexAdRequestError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex Banner: Banner ad failed to load with code ${error.code}: ${error.description}")
            }

            override fun onAdClicked() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex Banner: Banner ad clicked")
            }

            override fun onLeftApplication() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex Banner: Left application")
            }

            override fun onReturnedToApplication() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex Banner: Returned to application")
            }

            override fun onImpression(data: YandexImpressionData?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Yandex Banner: Impression: ${data?.rawData}")
            }
        })

        if (!SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion)
            bannerAd?.loadAd(adRequest)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        appUpdateManager
            .appUpdateInfo
            .addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                        appUpdateInfo,
                        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                        this,
                        8
                    )
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        bp.release()
        if (!disposable.isDisposed)
            disposable.dispose()
        yandexInterstitialAd?.destroy()
        yandexInterstitialAd = null
        bannerAd?.destroy()
        bannerAd = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onProductPurchased(productId: String, details: PurchaseInfo?) {
        showMessage(getString(R.string.snackbar_reset_app))
        SharedPreferencesManager.isFullVersion = true
    }

    override fun onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {}

    override fun onBillingError(errorCode: Int, error: Throwable?) {
        showMessage(error?.message)
    }

    override fun onBillingInitialized() {}

    // запуск уведомления о скачивании файла
    private fun startNotificationDownload() {
        notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID).apply {
            setContentTitle(getString(R.string.download_process))
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_download)
            priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW
        }

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
            notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true)
            //notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }

    // остановка уведомления о скачивании файла
    private fun stopNotificationDownload() {
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(getString(R.string.download_complete))
                .setProgress(0, 0, false)
            //notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
            cancel(1)
        }
    }

    // не работает с включенным VPN
    private fun downloadFileWithDM(url: String) {
        val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
            .setTitle("Загрузка изображения")
            .setMimeType("image/jpg")
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                File.separator + "PixabayLite" + File.separator + "pixabaylite_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"
            )
        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
        showMessage("Изображение будет сохранено в папку PixabayLite")
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your main activity code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the incompatibility of Gradle versions and the Splash Screen library. The Splash Screen library (com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0) doesn't work with Gradle 8.1. I had to go back Gradle to version 7.4.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).